# How to do I prevent NuGet asking about overwriting a file when restoring packages?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, nuget, teamcity, fody

We recently added Fody to some of our projects and locally this goes fine, but on the TeamCity build server, this causes problems, which I can replicate locally by running the following command in the *Package Manager Console* of VS2015:

```
PM> Update-package -reinstall
<snip ... />
Successfully uninstalled 'Fody 1.29.4' from Example.Project
Package 'Fody.1.29.4' already exists in folder 'D:\Projects\Examples\MySolutions\packages'
File Conflict
File 'FodyWeavers.xml' already exists in project 'Example.Project'. Do you want to overwrite it?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [?] Help (default is "N"):
```

On the build server, this message is repeated over and over until the logfile eats away all the free space on the data drive of the server (the last TC log became 28GB!)

I tried [`-NonInteractive`](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference), but this seems to have no effect on the build server, and locally, in the *Package Manager Console* it says it does not recognize that parameter:

```
PM> Update-package -reinstall -noninteractive
Update-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'noninteractive'.
At line:1 char:42
+ Update-package -reinstall -noninteractive <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Update-Package], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there actually is an option to prevent this behavior:

```
-FileConflictAction Ignore
```

This will take the default action (no overwrite).

In TeamCity you can set this option in your NuGet configuration (select Advanced Options), at the bottom, in *Command line parameters*:

[image: teamcity commandline parameters]

Comment: When I add this I get "Unknown option: '-FileConflictAction'"

Comment: @fet, there are a few bugs, check if you hit any of them, i.e. this is one https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3842

Comment: This option currently only seems to be available using the [Package Manager Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-update-package) even though the [NuGet CLI docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-update) say otherwise.