# TeamCity Nuget FileConflict - Reepeats [Y] Yes [A] Yes to All [N] No [L] No to All indefinitely

Tags: c#, nuget, teamcity

I have a TeamCity build process set up where the first of my steps is to restore NuGet packages as configured per this screenshot:

[image]

I then get repeated error messages such as:

[image]

I know that the recommended solution as presented here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34706342/223742) is to apply the **FileConflictAction**. However this is [not supported](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2321) in the NuGet CLI.

Naturally everything builds fine locally. Has anyone got any other suggestions on how to make this work in TeamCity?

Comment: FileConflictAction is not supported in nuget version 2.*. Did you try with 3.* or higher?

Comment: @Przemek Tried all the way to 4.50